# What is the appropriate way to compute $z=\frac{1}{\sqrt{7+24i}}?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

> What is the appropriate way to compute $$z=\frac{1}{\sqrt{7+24i}}?$$

I'm asking because in 2 different books I found 2 different answers for the problem:

Book A: $(4-3i)/25$ and $(-4+3i)/25$;

Book B: $(-4+3i)/25$.

To add to the confusion Wolfram Alpha gives the single answer $(4-3i)/25$, which I believe is correct by my own development.

The difficulty, I think, is on how to deal with the signs in the positive root of a complex number. This is not, I believe, the same thing as solving $z^2=1/(7+24i)$. Like, on reals, the problem of solving $x^2=4$ or computing $x=\sqrt{4}$.

I would appreciate some clarification, if possible.

Comment: What is the appropriate way to compute $\sqrt{4}$?  Book A gives $2$ and $-2$, while Book B gives just $2$.

Comment: @vadim123,  I would pick only 2 because what is asked is the positive $\sqrt{4}$, that is 2. 2 and -2 would be the solution for $x^2=4$. See below how both answers diverge....

Comment: I agree with @bluemaster, the main question is what is meant by $\sqrt{x}$, the principal square root, or all possible solutions. Most commonly, it represents the principal square root.

Comment: Wait?  *TWO* books had the *exact* same example?????

Comment: Could you explain how you say the books gave the answers they did?

Comment: @fleablood: Yes the same problem because it is from an entrance exam (IME 95). Entrance exam problems are often used in books as exercises.

Comment: @fleablood Book A just state the answer, no resolution provided. Book B presents a resolution... will give an outline in the next comment.

Comment: @fleablood Book B first squares both sides to get rid of the square root, and multiply the numerator and denominator by the conjugate of the numerator. Then finds the principal square root.  But notice that it diverges from WA solution.

Comment: Then it's a matter of which one is the *principal* square root.  Book A is listing both square roots which I think is missing the point as it is clearly written as that $\sqrt{7+24i} has a specific single value.  I'm not sure how book B justified the answer. $\sqrt{7 + 24i} = 4 + 3i$ (unambiguous as both 4,3 are positive. So $\frac 1{4 +3i} = \frac{4-3i}{25}$.

Answer (score 3):

Book A just gives the square root and its negative (both valid).

For a complex nonzero $w$ there are always two distinct solutions $z$ to $z^2=w.$ Though there may be some way to single out one of them as "the" square root, it's not that simple since complex numbers aren't ordered.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $$(4+3i)^2=16-9+24i$$ and $$\frac{1}{4+3i}=\frac{4-3i}{25}$$

Answer (score 2):

Correct answer is $ (4-3i)/25 $ as given by Wolfram Alpha. The real part of the principal square root is always nonnegative. ( Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root#Algebraic_formula )

Comment: Notice that the problem did not ask the solution of a second degree equation $z^2=...$.

Comment: I get your point @bluemaster. Let me edit the answer.